# Can i create a pre-controller hook in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

i'm new to laravel, just started building my first laravel application (v.5.2). I come from codeigniter. In CI i used to create a pre-controller hook to check login status and set language before any controller loads. Application-wide stuff.

I can't find anything on pre-controller hooks in the laravel docs. There is something called "middleware" however that might do the job. At what point does this Middleware kick in?
Am i on the right track? or is there a better way do these jobs in laravel.

Comment: It depends on what actions you want to perform. Middleware mainly comes into picture in situations like System should not allow restricted page access to anonymous user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, middleware is the best option. I'm using Auth Middleware to implement this kind of feature in my application.

Like below.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth' , ['except' => ['show']]);        
        parent::__construct($this);
    }
```

Here I want to give permission to only show action without login.

You can also use form request to check permission/authentication for each action.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that with middleware. 
Middleware will execute before hitting your controller's method.

Though I would suggest you to make a base controller where you can create a method to do this stuff and call that method from the constructor of the base class.

**Edit**

So I just read that you want to check if the user is logged in. For this purpose you have `auth` middleware.

Comment: Do you mean: create MyController extends Controller
and have all application controllers extend that one instead of Controller directly? HomeController extends MyController

Comment: Yup. I usually do this. You will need to do various common tasks which can be done from your base controller. But remember if the task is something like checking if user is logged in or is an admin etc then middlewares are your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

## For Laravel 5 # (5.2)

You can have a look on `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`

Actually all other controllers extends this base controller.

Issue : 
1. If routes are not use controller in this case it not works.